# Update table based on Dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I got below 2 tables:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null 
    drop table #t1

create table #t1 
(
     ID int, 
     opendate datetime, 
     closedate datetime,
     [ADDRESS] varchar(50)
)

insert into #t1 (ID, opendate, closedate)
values (111, '1930-05-01 00:00:00.000', '2004-10-23 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2004-10-23 00:00:00.000', '2006-03-26 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2006-10-23 00:00:00.000', '2009-03-26 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2009-03-26 00:00:00.000', '2013-05-21 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2013-05-21 00:00:00.000', '2013-06-18 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2013-06-18 00:00:00.000', '2016-04-11 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2016-04-11 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-16 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2016-06-16 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-21 00:00:00.000'),
       (111, '2016-06-21 00:00:00.000', NULL)

select 
    *
from 
    #t1

if object_id('tempdb..#t2') is not null 
    drop table #t2

create table #t2 
(
    ID int, 
    opendate datetime,
    closedate datetime,
    [ADDRESS] varchar(50) 
)

insert into #t2 (ID, opendate, closedate, [ADDRESS])
values  
 (111,'1930-05-01 00:00:00.000','2004-10-23 00:00:00.000','1 AVENUE'    )
,(111,'2004-10-23 00:00:00.000','2009-03-26 00:00:00.000','2 AVENUE'    )
,(111,'2009-03-26 00:00:00.000','2013-05-21 00:00:00.000','3 AVENUE'    )
,(111,'2013-05-21 00:00:00.000' ,NULL                     ,'5 AVENUE' )
,(111,'2016-04-11 00:00:00.000' ,'2016-06-16 00:00:00.000','6 AVENUE'   )
,(111,'2016-06-16 00:00:00.000' ,NULL                     ,'7 AVENUE'   )
,(111,'2016-06-21 00:00:00.000' ,NULL                     ,'8 AVENUE'   )


select 
    *
from 
    #t2
```

I want update first table like below:

```
111 1930-05-01 00:00:00.000 2004-10-23 00:00:00.000 '1 AVENUE'
111 2004-10-23 00:00:00.000 2006-03-26 00:00:00.000 '2 AVENUE'
111 2006-03-26 00:00:00.000 2009-03-26 00:00:00.000 '2 AVENUE'
111 2009-03-26 00:00:00.000 2013-05-21 00:00:00.000 '3 AVENUE'
111 2013-05-21 00:00:00.000 2013-06-18 00:00:00.000 '5 AVENUE'
111 2013-06-18 00:00:00.000 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 '5 AVENUE'
111 2016-04-11 00:00:00.000 2016-06-16 00:00:00.000 '6 AVENUE'
111 2016-06-16 00:00:00.000 2016-06-21 00:00:00.000 '7 AVENUE'
111 2016-06-21 00:00:00.000 NULL                    '8 AVENUE'
```

I have tried some ways but it is not returning the correct results because of nulls.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to update #t1 table Address field based on the #t2 table ID and open date and close date.

Comment: let me explain this way, If #t1 opendate is between #t2 open and close dates then it should update address field. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update t1 set address = tmp.address
from (select t1.ID, t1.opendate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.opendate order by t2.opendate desc) row, t2.ADDRESS
    from #t1 t1
    inner join #t2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.opendate between t2.opendate and isnull(t2.closedate, t1.opendate)) tmp
inner join #t1 t1 on t1.ID = tmp.ID and t1.opendate = tmp.opendate and tmp.row = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Čajbík, it's working fine. you are awesome man.